# Spring Security Version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have spring security jars in non spring project.Which version of spring-security-oauth2 should i use ?Currently i am using 2.3.5 .Is this compatible with spring security core 5.3.4.RELEASE?

I am getting the below error while fetching Outh2 tokens

> post request for resulted in 401 (unauthorized) invoking error handler

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [`spring-security-oauth2` is deprecated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/README.md) in favor of `spring-security-oauth2-client` and `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server`.

The new dependencies are released along with `spring-security-core`. So, if you change to the newer jars, then you can achieve compatibility by choosing the same version number:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

As was already noted by Pale Blue Dot, `spring-security-oauth2-client` will bring in `spring-security-core` transitively, so you can leave out the `spring-security-core` dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be explicitly importing `spring-security-core` as `spring-security-oauth2` already imports it transitively.

Comment: u mean i should delete spring-security-core and just use spring-security-oauth2 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that!

Comment: Ok thanks..let me try..FYI ..it's a non spring boot project.Thats why we have to handle it manually